# I'm trying to set up ruby on rails git deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk; "eb init" failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Running `eb init` from within my repo seems to go through the configuration options fine but at the end gives:

```
local variable 'fullpath' referenced before assignment
```

The config file does seem to be created OK within .elasticbeanstalk but "eb start" gives the same error:

```
local variable 'fullpath' referenced before assignment
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

More details:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because it can't find the `AWSDevTools` folder on your system (judging from the source code). You should move the whole folder to the root, e.g.:

```
/AWSDevTools
```

Furthermore, there seems to be a bug in their `core.py` that prevents anything useful from being printed to the console.

However, you can modify your `logconfig.json` file and find these lines:

```
"root": {
    "level": "NONE"
},
```

Change it into this:

```
"root": {
    "level": "DEBUG"
},
```

When you run `eb init` or `eb start` again it will create a log file called `eb-cli.log`. Looking inside will tell you where it expects the folder.

See also this [forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=399709#jive-message-408956).