# Elastic Beanstalk failed to update local Git configuration - Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
> eb init
(Answered all questions)

Failed to update local Git configuration. Follow the instructions at "http://doc
s.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started
.html" to set up your Git repository, and then try again.
local variable 'fullpath' referenced before assignment
```

- My platform is Windows.
- I have followed all the instructions from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_flask.html
- Git (git-scm) works from the command line.
- GIT_SSH path has been set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe`

I have looked at two other questions which are similar but they haven't helped,

- [Elastic Beanstalk failed to update local Git configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246615/elastic-beanstalk-failed-to-update-local-git-configuration)
- [I'm trying to set up ruby on rails git deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk; "eb init" failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289271/im-trying-to-set-up-ruby-on-rails-git-deployment-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-eb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set your PATH to the location of **eb**. like the following :

```
C:\> set PATH=%PATH%;<path_to_unzipped_EB_CLI_package>\eb\windows\
```

for me , I put the [AWS Sample Code & Libraries](http://aws.amazon.com/code/6752709412171743) folder on my C drive , So the link above must be

```
C:\AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.5.1\eb\windows\
```

Make sure that you have all the **AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.5.1** folder contents; **eb** and **api** folders

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is the correct answer.  If the path variable wasn't configured properly beforehand, wouldn't the problem be that the "eb init" command isn't recognized?  I've followed the same instructions to a T, and ran into the exact same issue, despite having a properly set path.