# Elastic Beanstalk failed to update local Git configuration on Windows

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently unable to set up my EB because I am having trouble finishing the eb init.

I have this error:

```
 > eb init
(Answered all questions)

Failed to update local Git configuration. Follow the instructions at "http://doc
s.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started
.html" to set up your Git repository, and then try again.
```

I have looked at other questions, including [Elastic Beanstalk failed to update local Git configuration - Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393646/elastic-beanstalk-failed-to-update-local-git-configuration-windows?rq=1), but it nothing there worked for me.  I also do not have a 
local variable error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should run `$ git init` first to initialize Git repository. EB will install some of the tools under `.git`.